# Json flattening python

Tags: python, json, flatten, json-flattener

My goal is to identify which instanse is `dict`, `str` or `list` under the `items` hierarchy.

```
def flatten(data):
    for i, item in enumerate(data['_embedded']['items']):
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            print('Item', i, 'is a dict')
        elif isinstance(item, list):
            print('Item', i, 'is a list')
        elif isinstance(item, str):
            print('Item', i, 'is a str')
        else:
            print('Item', i, 'is unknown')
flatten(data)
```

Output of this code is:

```
Item 0 is a dict
Item 1 is a dict
Item 2 is a dict
Item 3 is a dict
Item 4 is a dict
```

Desired out put should access the keys (`identifier`, `enabled`,`family`) inside the `0`, `1` etc.

for a better udnerstnading of the structure of the JSON file please see the image
[image]

Comment: You need a nested for-loop or some kind of recursion to inspect the dictionaries.

Comment: yeah I tried to  something liek this to reach lower level `def flatten (data):
    for element in data['_embedded']:
        for element['items'] in element:
            print(element['items'])

flatten(data)` but getting error `'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: If "value" is a dict, you can just iterate over its keys or items with an additional for-loop in the if-block. Something like `for element['items'] in element` usually doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to recursively print the type of every field. To do that, you can simply call the function again in the case the object you find is a dictionnary.
It would look like :

```
def flatten(data):
    for key, value in data['_embedded']['items']:
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print(key + ' is dict')
            flatten(value)
        [...]
```

This way you will keep entering nested dictionnaries and displaying them just as you did for the outer one.